# How to extract values from json using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having the following code:

```
data = JSON.stringify({
    "result": [
        {
            "username": "username should not empty"
        },
        {
            "password": "password should not empty"
        }
    ],
    "validate_flag": 1
})
data = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(data,function(index,value){
   console.log(index);
    console.log(value);
});
console.log(data);
```

Here I can extract the second key "validate_flag" directly using $.each. But when I tried to extract "result" I got two objects. Now,how can I effectively use $.each() to extract the following json regardless of multi-dimensional or single-dimensional. Also how can I access object in the key value "username" and "password"? Here is the [link for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zds6M/) I tried?

Comment: Might help you http://jsfiddle.net/zds6M/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/zds6M/3/

```
var echoOut = function(data){
    $.each(data,function(i,v){
        if(typeof v == 'object'){
            console.log('In: ' + i);
            echoOut(v);
        }else{
            console.log(i + ': ' + v);
        }
   });
};

data = JSON.parse(data);
echoOut(data);
```

Answer (score -2):

properties of an object in javascript can be accessed via 
for in loop

```
for (var x in yourobject)
  {
 // key is x 
// value is object[x]
  }
```

if you already know the property name

than use can use `yourobject["propertyname"] or yourobject.propertyname`

Comment: That's precisely what `$.each()` does, this doesn't really help answer the question.